# Flask, post JSON data and render template

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

I have a problem trying to render a template using Flask on python.

My python file looks like:

**main.py**

```
@app.route('/')
def acc_prop():

    return render_template("layout.html")


@app.route('/sub_form2', methods=['POST'])
def submitted_form2():
    print "enter submitted_form2"

    dataset = request.get_json(force=True)
    data1 = dataset['c1']
    data2 = dataset['c2']

    print data1
    print data2

    return render_template(
        "submitted_form2.html",
        one=data1,
        two=data2
    )
```

And my templates are the following:

**layout.html**

```
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div>
         <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg float-right" id="send-data">Next</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/send-data.js"></script>
</body>
```

**submitted_form2.html**

```
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <p>Data received:</p>
    <p>
        <strong>First data: </strong> {{ one }} <br>
        <strong>Second data: </strong> {{ two }} <br>
    </p>
</body>
```

The first template `layout.html` is well rendering, and the java script file is supossed to send a json data to `submitted_form2()` function in my flask project when the button `Next` is pressed, then enter the function correctly but not render the template inside `submitted_form2.html`.

the java script use `ajax` to preform a POST with a JSON data as follow:

**send-data.js**

```
$("#send-data").click(function(){
    alert('Enter the ajax code');

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/sub_form2",
        contentType : "application/json",
        data : JSON.stringify({"c1": "one", "c2": "two"}),
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success: " + data);
        }
    });
});
```

when I press the `Next` button the message `Enter the ajax code` is showing as espected, but the template `submitted_form2.html` is not rendering.

The console print

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2018 11:32:03] "POST /sub_form2 HTTP/1.1" 400 -
enter submitted_form2
```

But the `data1` and `data2` not printed.

I was testing with postman trying to send a json to `/sub_form2` and it works, see the image.

[json in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V06jI.png)

and the console prints:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2018 11:32:03] "POST /sub_form2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
enter submitted_form2
uno
[1, 2, 3]
```

Why is this happening? maybe there is something that I don't know, or something that I'm doing wrong. My first apreciation is that my java script is NOT really sending the JSON data, for that reason is not printing `data1` and `data2`.

Sorry for the amount of code blocks, but I don't know what to do now, I tried everything and the problem persist. If you have a better solution please help me!

*Note: sorry, english is not my natal tongue.*

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem but couldn't.

This is a minimal example, which did exactly what was expected.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
    <button id="send-data">test</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    alert('working')
      $("#send-data").click(function(){
          alert('Enter the ajax code');

          $.ajax({
              type : "POST",
              url : "/process_form",
              contentType : "application/json",
              data : JSON.stringify({"c1": "one", "c2": "two"}),
              dataType: "json",
              async: false,
              success: function(data) {
                  alert("success: " + data);
              }
          });
      });

    </script>
    ''')

@app.route('/process_form', methods=['POST'])
def process_form():
    inputted_json = request.get_json(force=True)
    print(inputted_json['c1'])
    return 'yes'
```

But if you want to render another template after sending an (AJAX) request, don't use AJAX at all, but just send in the form normally.

Comment: maybe its not possible to mix get_json() with render_template() probably because the AJAX is trying to receive infomation to use in the same template. What a problem!